# easy way to determine if a string CAN'T be a valid regex

Tags: python, regex, parsing, delimiter

I have a config file that the user can specify sections, and then within those section they can specify regular expressions. I have to parse this config file and separate the regex's into the various sections.

Is there an easy way to delimitate a regex from a section header? I was thinking just the standard

```
[section]
regex1
regex2
```

But I just realized that [section] is a valid regex. So I'm wondering if there's a way I can format a section header so that it can ONLY be understood as a section header and not a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an unlimited ways of making an invalid regexp, but the first thing that comes to mind would be

```
*section*
```

You can't have a quantifier (`*`) at the start of the regexp.

(The other `*` is there just to satisfy my obsession for symmetry.)

Comment: Nice simple solution. `*` is better anyway since I can just `.strip('*')` it away instead of having to add the albeit minorly more complicated `.strip('[]')`

Comment: Please don't make up your own weird little configuration format with such a bizarre design as "uses * at the start of the line to distinguish from regular expressions".  Use XML or JSON or Lua; don't litter the world with yet another unnecessary custom file format.

Comment: So I should rather use an awkward xml format when what I'm trying to do can be done with a simple line

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your problem domain, so I don't know what forms of regex you're expecting, but it seems to me you should keep your section formatting as it is.  A regex that starts with [ and ends with ] and has no square brackets in between is quite unusual.  It can only match a single character.  So leave the section headers as they are.  Strictly speaking, they are valid regexes, but they probably aren't interesting regexes.

Also, why not use `ConfigParser` from the standard library, and let it do the parsing for you?

Comment: I thought about using ConfigParser except my options are key,value pairs. And while I could work around that, I need to maintain the order of the options under the section. I realize there are python3.0 solutions using ordered_dict, but I need it to work under 2.6.5. And it's not THAT complex that it's worth having to use custom or futures modules when I can just write it myself.

Answer (score 0):

There are easy ways, but they all require changing your format:

1. Use indentation, similar to how Python source is interpreted.  Leading spaces would need special handling, e.g. "(?: )abc" instead of " abc".
2. Use an INI format, where each item in a section requires a name=value pair.
3. Use some sort of list syntax.  [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) will be helpful.

   ```
   section1 = [
     "regex 1",
     "2",
     "3",
   ]
   section2 = ["..."]
   ```

**Primarily, don't invent your own format**, or make it as close to a known format as you can.  The third is a subset of Python syntax, for example, and you could even use raw string literals naturally.

JSON or YAML may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, please don't invent yet another config format. Use the Python Standard Library's [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html), which will be able to parse the [section] notation exactly as you have shown it.

EDIT: The allow_no_value option allows you to to just have a single entry, rather than a key/value pair. And the default dict type is OrderedDict, so it will maintain order.